# Taxonomy API in Java or Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json, taxonomy

I was wondering if there is any api or library  available that provides a taxonomy for a given term in jSON.

For instance, if the argument is Shoes, it should return a data structure consisting of all the synonmys or types of shoes like Boots, Flip-flops, Slippers, Stilettos, and so on..

Thanks :)

Comment: Isn't that what JSON format takes care of? If you organize your data correctly, it should be easy to access what you want. For example, the structure `{"shoes": {"boots": "info", "flip-flops": "info"}, "movies": {"comedy": "info", "romance": "info"}}`

Comment: I don't think you're after taxonomy (that is about classification and suggests a hierarchial structure), you seem more interested in a thesaurus (alternative terms, antonyms, preferred terms, etc.). And XML or EDI are likely a far more approriate than JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the Java API for WordNet

http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html

You can wrap this inside a servlet and call it via jquery in your application.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is not typed by itself, you have to use another notation to add type to the data encoded in JSON. [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/) for example allows to add the concepts of linked data/semantic web to the [json](/questions/tagged/json) data. Using this information it is possible to query the taxonomy that defines the structure of the data.

Comment: Or you forget JSON and use XML.